# Gitlab API access to package registry file

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

trying to get my .war file with the GitLab API, how to do that ?

I got this route : /api/v4/projects/:id/packages/:package_id/package_files
to get list of files, but how to get the file content from this data response ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

let's assume you have these responses:
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/8377576/packages/25/package_files:

```
[{
        "id": 101,
        "package_id": 25,
        "created_at": "2018-09-14T07:41:10.409Z",
        "file_name": "my-app-1.4-20180914.074110-1.jar",
        "size": 2497,
        "file_md5": "2f94a9760bcd7c2be781b938ec825205",
        "file_sha1": "63d4153372057e12ca8e539c5fcae82b7b110e45"
    }, {
        "id": 102,
        "package_id": 25,
        "created_at": "2018-09-14T07:41:10.843Z",
        "file_name": "my-app-1.4-20180914.074110-1.pom",
        "size": 1429,
        "file_md5": "380bbe1891b4d568f823f5562875b12b",
        "file_sha1": "2406e3f80700ff1579a255858b8dcab35ef9ee4e"
    }, {
        "id": 103,
        "package_id": 25,
        "created_at": "2018-09-14T07:41:11.250Z",
        "file_name": "maven-metadata.xml",
        "size": 767,
        "file_md5": "994e0bf8f19bc1c6fdfaf821e9e65037",
        "file_sha1": "1462cf5d9ba09e67848202d67cafa3c7e1034a9d"
    }, {
        "id": 106,
        "package_id": 25,
        "created_at": "2018-09-14T07:41:24.324Z",
        "file_name": "my-app-1.4-20180914.074123-1.jar",
        "size": 2505,
        "file_md5": "a75078cae821223e7ac6d9055cca24b6",
        "file_sha1": "7eca3cba2d25225382e079381cb4b0616528552f"
    }, {
        "id": 107,
        "package_id": 25,
        "created_at": "2018-09-14T07:41:25.521Z",
        "file_name": "my-app-1.4-20180914.074123-1.pom",
        "size": 1429,
        "file_md5": "380bbe1891b4d568f823f5562875b12b",
        "file_sha1": "2406e3f80700ff1579a255858b8dcab35ef9ee4e"
    }, {
        "id": 108,
        "package_id": 25,
        "created_at": "2018-09-14T07:41:27.257Z",
        "file_name": "maven-metadata.xml",
        "size": 767,
        "file_md5": "938e53442dbe0e513bf99ac35a721a30",
        "file_sha1": "3d71c2f7064fdf016a70ccddf27d879af7a08d47"
    }
]
```

assuming you want the file `my-app-1.4-20180914.074110-1.pom`, you can download it by using the url:
`https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/examples/mvn-example/-/package_files/102/download`
(you should know your group name, project name etc.)

** gitlab does not have a proper way to do this. this is a workaround
Reference:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/271534

Comment: if the repo is private, is that a way to download it through this url ? https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/examples/mvn-example/-/package_files/102/download

Comment: yes, as you can also add the private token key `curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" ....` as stated in the docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html

Comment: not working with the url above and the token in header.

Comment: Founded a way but got another error using generic API :
/projects/:id/packages/generic/:package_name/:package_version/:file_name
But got an "package_version is invalid"
This is the route call with token
"https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<projectId>/packages/generic/test/api-test/0.0.1/api-test-0.0.1.war"